# How does List<Struct>.Contains() work?

Tags: .net

I have programed a very simple struct in C# (I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5)

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public Int32 X { get; set; }
    public Int32 Y { get; set; }

}
```

When I perform the following test to compare two different structs using equality operator `==`:

```
private void MyTest()
{
    var sA = new MyStruct() { X = 1, Y = 2 };
    var sB = new MyStruct() { X = 10, Y = 20 };

    // Expected error occurs here.
    Console.WriteLine(sA == sB ? "true" : "false");

}
```

I get the expected error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyStruct' and 'MyStruct'.`  Nothing new or interesting here.  However, here's where things get weird.  Let's say I try to do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sA = new MyStruct() { X = 10, Y = 10 };
    var sB = new MyStruct() { X = 20, Y = 20 };
    var sC = new MyStruct() { X = 30, Y = 30 };
    var sD = new MyStruct() { X = 10, Y = 10 };

    // Note that struct sD contains the same data as sA.

    var myList = new List<MyStruct>();

    myList.Add(sA);
    myList.Add(sB);

    // This line writes "true" to the console window.
    Console.WriteLine(myList.Contains(sA) ? "true" : "false");

    // This line writes "true" to the console window.
    Console.WriteLine(myList.Contains(sB) ? "true" : "false");

    // This line writes "false" to the console window.
    Console.WriteLine(myList.Contains(sC) ? "true" : "false");

    // This line writes "true" to the console window.
    Console.WriteLine(myList.Contains(sD) ? "true" : "false");

}
```

How does the `.Contains()` method perform the comparison?  It's clearly not comparing references since it indicates that sD is in the list.  It seems like it's going into the structs and comparing  them property by property (e.g. `sA.X == sD.X` and `sA.Y == sD.Y`). Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: One of the ways you can see different teams making different choices.  The CLR implements the Equals() method for struct types, they could not say "no" since there's no alternative.  Operator overloads are a language implementation detail, the CLR stays out of the way.  The C# team *could* have auto-generated one, but they didn't.  They probably didn't like the extra clutter and surely didn't like the promise.

Comment: @HansPassant Very interesting comment...food for thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does the .Contains() method perform the comparison?

It uses the default equality comparer for the type, as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx):

> This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer

So essentially, something like this (but with null handling too):

```
var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
foreach (var item in this)
{
    if (comparer.Equals(item, target))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

`EqualityComparer<MyStruct>.Default` will just perform a simple comparison on the fields, although I'd urge you to override `Equals` and implement `IEquatable<T>` on the struct yourself - as well as making it immutable.

Comment: @John_Skeet Thanks for this!  I will do as you suggest and override Equals() and implement IEquatable<T> on my struct.  Cheers!